# How does Java supports architectural neutrality by specifying the behavior of its arithmetic operators?

Tags: java, types, arithmetic-expressions

I was reading the Java Language Environment document at(https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/introduction-to-java.html). In this paper, it is mentioned that

> "Java technology puts a stake in the ground and specifies the sizes of its basic data types and the behavior of its arithmetic operators."

I know that in C/C++ the fundamental types are not strictly defined as in Java. But I do not understand the "behavior of arithmetic operators" part. Does the author mean that in C/C++ the behavior of arithmetic operators(on fundamental data types) is compiler/platform-dependent? If so, can anyone provide an example of how this above-mentioned behavior is different in Java when compared to C/C++ (or any other language)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/3890632 might be of interest.

Comment: "Does the author mean that in C/C++ the behavior of arithmetic operators is compiler/platform-dependent?" The sentence you quoted says nothing about C/C++.

Comment: Many things about the shift operators are undefined, i.e. left up to the CPU architecture, in both C and C++, which BTW are two separate languages.

Comment: @khelwood, thanks for the link. It was very useful.

Comment: @Sweeper, It does not say anything specifically about C or C++, but since Java was meant to be an OOP language that built on better features of C++ and also provided Architectural neutrality and portability, I assumed it was a fair comparison.

Comment: @user207421 In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64832034/#comment114625829_64832115) to a now-deleted answer, you claimed that integer overflow was undefined in Java. So I want to point you to [JLS §15.18.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2-400): “*If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format. If overflow occurs, then the sign of the result is not the same as the sign of the mathematical sum of the two operand values.*”